# SugarCRM goes to blank screen after clicking save (Accounts module). No changes made overnight

Tags: apache, ubuntu, sugarcrm

and thank you for any help you can offer.

My instance of Sugar 6.5.21 CE suddenly began giving us a white screen of death when trying to create and save a new Account. Specifically, clicking "Save" immediately brings up a blank white page. Firefox and Chrome.

No changes were made to the system overnight, and yesterday and every day before, our staff was creating Accounts no problem. Now instead of saving, we get redirected to blank white page. Not inside Sugar but outside, where no menus or interface or HTML of any kind loads.

All other parts of our system have continued to work as normal, including saving new records in other modules.

None of the logs show anything new or Fatal. We have hard disk space and RAM to spare. It does not appear to be a mysql error since I don't believe the mysql queries are ever sent to the server.

Furthermore, I have tried restoring backups of the system from a day, a week, a month ago (when we had no problem saving new Accounts) and I get *the same result* on save. This part is truly bewildering to me.

If you have experienced this or have any advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

White screen usually indicates a PHP error. Check the PHP logs and also be sure that error_reporting is set correctly in your php.ini as well as display_errors = on. Restart Apache after any php.ini changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call a quick repair to fix it.

Comment: this should be as comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions. Turns out the problem was the fault of a logic hook. We have a script running to interface with Google Drive, and for some still unknown reason, the Oauth (which has been fine for over a year) suddenly stopped working.

Once the auth failed, the script just quit and never got back to Sugar. That's why no evidence in Sugar/Apache/mysql/system logs. On to the next problem........